# How to handle the user registration and login process? (spring boot + angular)

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

Maybe this is a trivial question, however, I will be doing this for the first time, so I have been searching the Internet for some time to find a suitable source with an example of how to make such an implementation (spring boot + angular), most tutorials are based on examples from a few years ago, and some solutions no longer work.

To the point, in the application I already have a form for user registration and a login panel. However, I would obviously like to add a registration and login "process" to it. How would I go about doing this, for example, user registration with email confirmation, and then login using the previously provided data. How would you approach this topic, what tools, libraries, etc. would you use?

Thanks in advance for any comments in the discussion!

Comment: You should not post a question like this here. You can find hundreds of tutorials and articles. https://www.bezkoder.com/angular-14-spring-boot-jwt-auth/

Comment: use jwt https://www.javatpoint.com/angular-spring-login-and-logout-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should start by drawing an ERD diagram, so that you know how manu logic classes you need, how many entities, the relationship etc